# Can I load flask data to .vue template? How?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, vue.js, flask

So I'm building this app with a flask (Back-end) and Vue (Front-end) and I want to load data from flask directly to my `.vue` template but whenever I try to `{{some_variable}}` or in my case `$[[some_variable]]`, cuz I have it set up in Jinja like that, it returns an error being either $ not defined or when I tried without the $ being `[[some_variable]]` not defined. I also tried using `vars|tojson` it returns an error. I also tried loading it to js as a string but does nothing.

**In case you got confused this is what I tried:**

`{{some_variable}}` in template and script tag

`[[some_variable]]` in the template and script tag this returned a not defined error in a script tag and did nothing in the template

`$[[some_variable]]` in template and script tag this returned a $ not defined error in a script tag and did nothing in the template

`vars|tojson` simply didn't work

`'{{some_variable}}' '$[[some_variable]]' '[[some_variable]]'` in script tag did nothing

**My Jinja config:**

```
class CustomFlask(Flask):
    jinja_options = Flask.jinja_options.copy()
    jinja_options.update(dict(
        block_start_string='$[',
        block_end_string=']',
        variable_start_string='$[[',
        variable_end_string=']]',
        comment_start_string='$(',
        comment_end_string=')',
    ))

app = CustomFlask(__name__,static_folder=STATIC_PATH, static_url_path='', template_folder=TEMPLATE_PATH)
```

So my question is if its possible and how can I do it.

PS: I'm routing with flask and not vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need Ajax to do that, like fetch or axios library to get backend data in your Vue component file.

Comment: Thats what I'm doing but since I'm routing using flask I thought I could load data in the render_template .

Comment: i think, ajax we should use to dynamically change something or perform operations after we load the page. There should be some other way pass data from flask on initial page load.